# How to prove this lemma 1?

Tags: statistics, laplace-transform

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mbqVK.png)

I want to know How to calculate Laplace transform of $Y^2-1$.

I'm posting a question because I want to know that part and the middle part omitted from the proof in more detail.

Lastly, please tell me how Corollary of Lemma 1 was induced and the math subjects I need to understand the proof.

Thank you.

Paper : ADAPTIVE ESTIMATION OF A QUADRATIC FUNCTIONAL BY MODEL SELECTION, The Annals of Statistics, 2000